# How to make some code run only in debug build target?

Tags: c++, codeblocks, wxwidgets

I want to use some extra code to easily debuging and testing. But I don't want to add this code to "Release" binary.
Is there some defined preprocessor symbol for build target? Otherwise, what condition i need to use to achieve this?

Comment: Usually depends on platform. debug buuilds have a DEBUG or _DEBUG macro defined

Comment: I tried both, they are undefined. BTW, Windows7 platform

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image: Project Build Options]

I would recommend you create your own pre-processor macro and name it according to the functionality of the extra code, e.g. something equivalent to

```
#define LOG_ALL_SQL 1
```

That way, you can turn on and off the individual functions that you are using. You might have another, equivalent to

```
#define PRINT_STATUS 1
```

You can then adjust your debugging, e.g. sometimes setting them as follows

```
#define LOG_ALL_SQL 1
#define PRINT_STATUS 0
```

so that SQL statements would be logged, but the status would not be printed.

I'd use these in the software as in the following example ...

```
#if defined(LOG_ALL_SQL) && LOG_ALL_SQL 
    conditional SQL logging code here;
#endif // LOG_ALL_SQL

#if defined(PRINT_STATUS) && PRINT_STATUS 
    conditional status printing code here;
#endif // PRINT_STATUS
```

The advantage of defining the macros using values (0 and 1, or TRUE and FALSE, etc) is that if some debugging functionality is turned off because that part is not currently required, the definition is still present, so there is a reminder for how to reactivate it, or to tell you what debugging software is present but currently unused.

The symbols used for the debugging then should be defined in your development environment, for the Debug version (and not for the Release version).

Answer (score 2):

What's wrong with the usual `#ifdef DEBUG`?  If you write your own make files, make sure to define the macro for debug build.

Comment: What's wrong with it is that the canonical pattern is `#ifndef NDEBUG`. Most compilers undef `NDEBUG` automatically in debug builds.

Comment: Well, I see `#ifdef DEBUG` quite often and NODEBUG really occasionally.  Can't even think about when was the last time I saw it.

Comment: GCC-TDM on Windows 7 hasn't this symbol at all.

Comment: This is what `-D` switch is for, of course! :)  How could the compiler know if you want debug or release build???

Comment: gcc won't define NDEBUG automatically for you on its own, but IDEs normally will. If not, you should go ahead and modify your project/makefile/whatever.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't know. Code::Blocks create all environments for me. I don't work with compiler directly.

Comment: Ok, there must be a way to define a macro in the IDE - look under the build config.  Since I have never used that particular one I can't tell you exactly where it should be, but there must be a way to do that :)

Comment: Project->Build options->Release-># defines

Answer (score 1):

Do not rely on preprocessor, macros are a quick and dirty way to do the job, and if you do so, don't use the `DEBUG` or `NDEBUG` macros.

Reason: I've seen more than one people forcing to enable assertion even in release mode in the following way (so there are chances actually those macros are already setted/unsetted by bad designed code):

```
#undef NDEBUG
#include <assert.h>
```

So or do you define your own macro like `PROJECT_NAME_ENABLE_SOMETHING` or just use a [custom logger](http://www.drdobbs.com/cpp/a-lightweight-logger-for-c/240147505) (wich you will keep as empty implementation in release mode while it will print something meaningfully during debug).

Using "debug only code" if done with no care, most times introduce bugs, it also hurts when your "debug only code" needs something that live outside the preprocessor because it force changes in "release code" that sometimes compiler would not be able to remove.

In general you should do [unit testing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_testing) on each component of the application insted of clubbering your code with "debug code".

Answer (score 0):

In Code::Blocks in the *Project->Build options...* in the *Compiler Setings* tab I found *#defines* tab and added symbol for Debug target by my own.